# Deitar fora e jogar fora

Tags: etimologia, diferenças-transatlânticas

Aquilo que não querem mais, os brasileiros jogam fora, enquanto os portugueses deitam fora. É verdade que o Aulete digital apresenta [deitar fora](http://www.aulete.com.br/deitar) como sinónimo de [jogar fora](http://www.aulete.com.br/jogar) e sem o classificar como lusitanismo. O dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa também apresenta as duas expressões sem classificar qualquer uma delas como lusitanismo ou brasileirismo.

Quer-me parecer contudo que a minha caracterização inicial está correta. A minha pergunta é então: já se disse *deitar fora* no Brasil, ou ainda se diz nalgum lugar? Quando é que deixou de ser comum usá-lo. E em Portugal já se disse *jogar fora* (sem querer dizer *fora de casa*), ou ainda se diz algures? Quando é que deixou de ser usado?

Comment: "Jogar" não se usa de facto muito em Lisboa, mas pelo menos no Algarve é comum.

Comment: E usam o gerúndio também... deve ser do sol.

Comment: Ainda há o _tacar fora_ e o _botar fora_, que eu usava muito no Rio.

Comment: *Tacar* eu não apanhava. *Botar*, ainda lá ia. Mas é outro verbo que não se usa em Portugal, mas que eu creio que se já usou.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, já ouvi dizerem "deitar fora" muitas vezes aqui no Brasil.  Minha mãe, que é portuguesa, ainda o diz. E muitos portugueses radicados no Brasil também o dizem. Mas deixando de lado essa tentativa de humor, tua suposição está correta: já não se usa "deitar fora" no Brasil. Pode ser que algum brasileiro o diga em algum momento, mas não é idiomático. Se já foi usado em ptBR?  Bem, supondo que "deitar fora" não seja uma aquisição recente do ptPT, e que já venha sendo usado há alguns séculos, acredito que sim. Até o século dezenove ptPT e ptBR eram bem semelhantes.  Acredito que tenha sido abandonado em algum momento no século vinte. No entanto isso é uma impressão pessoal, uma vez que não tenho nenhuma fonte como referência.

Atualmente dizemos: jogar fora, descartar, ir para o lixo, jogar no lixo, por fora, etc.
exemplos:

- "Você jogou fora o resto de comida?"
- "D. Isaura, toda essa papelada que separei não presta pra nada e deve ser descartada."
- "Tu vais por fora esse resto de tinta?"
- "Tudo isso aqui vai pro lixo."

Quanto a outros usos de "deitar" como verbo transitivo, usamos em diversas situações.  Ocorre-me no momento seu uso em receitas culinárias: "deite a massa sobre um... e espere meia hora...".

Comment: O teu raciocínio parece ser: no ptPT atual diz-se *deitar fora*, portanto no ptBR já se deve ter dito *deitar fora* . Mas isto é inválido: temos por exemplo o caso de *estar a dormir, estar a comer* do ptPT atual enquanto no ptBR é *estar dormindo, estar comendo*; no Brasil sempre se disse *estar dormindo*; *estar a dormir* é um inovação recente do ptPT. O ptPT atual não é a raiz do ptBR atual: ptPT e ptBR são ambos ramos de uma raiz comum.

Comment: Acrescentaria mais: o facto de em Portugal se ouvir dialectalmente "jogar" sugere que foi Portugal que passou a preteri-la (embora possa também ser que nunca tenha sido comum em Lisboa).

Comment: @Jacinto  Modifiquei um pouco a resposta "to hedge my bets".